# How to save Label.Text values to Excel in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am trying to save values of `label.text` to an Excel file. The values of the labels came from a database that I am using.

Here is my code:

.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br /><br />
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["id"] != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Stock Keeping Unit: " + Request.QueryString["StockKeepingUnit"];
        Label2.Text = "Universal Product Code: " + Request.QueryString["UniversalProductCode"];
        Label3.Text = "Vendor Name: " + Request.QueryString["VendorName"];
        Label4.Text = "Product Name: " + Request.QueryString["ProductName"];
        Label5.Text = "Product Description: " + Request.QueryString["ProductDesc"];
        Label6.Text = "Retail Price: " + Request.QueryString["RetailPrice"];
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
    }
}

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] information = { Label1.Text, Label2.Text, Label3.Text, Label4.Text, Label5.Text, Label6.Text };
    string path = @"C:\Users\hac9289\source\repos\WebAppRetail";

    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, "RetailInformation.xls")))
    {
        foreach (string info in information)
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(info);
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "New record added successfully", "alert('Record Saved');", true);
    }
}
```

However, the values that are saved in the Excel file looked liked this:

[Excel data look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la4iK.png)

It seems that every words were put to a cell. How can I code it to have 2 columns only? Like this:

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iGsT.png)

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: An Excel file is not just a text file with the extension XLS, it is far more complicated. Either write a CSV file, or use a library specifically for writing Office documents.

Comment: @IanKemp what library should i use for excel?

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus